# Laravel modifying model, after retrieving data

Tags: php, object, orm, laravel

I don't want to modify the object when ever I call it, and I am looking that upon call, the modifications are done automatically.

In a controller, I have the following:

```
$candidate = Candidate::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

And then I do:

```
if (!is_null($candidate->social_profiles) && !empty($candidate->social_profiles)) {
    $candidate->social_profiles = unserialize($candidate->social_profiles);

    foreach ($candidate->social_profiles as $key => $value) {
        $candidate->{$key} = $value;
    }

    $candidate->social_profiles = null;
}
```

Now, I am looking for a way, to do the last part, inside the very own `Candidate` model, so that whenever a candidate is retrieved, it does the code above, that way I wont have to duplicate the last part above, wherever I get a candidate.

The problem is, that I don't know where to do so. `$this` in `__construct` contains only data defined in the class, which is basically an empty model. What else?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably personal taste, but I would create a CandidateRespository class that has a method findBySlug (or whatever you'd like to call it):

```
public function findBySlug($slug)
{
    $candidate = Candidate::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    if (!is_null($candidate->social_profiles) && !empty($candidate->social_profiles)) {
        $candidate->social_profiles = unserialize($candidate->social_profiles);

        foreach ($candidate->social_profiles as $key => $value) {
            $candidate->{$key} = $value;
        }

        $candidate->social_profiles = null;
    }

    return $candidate;
}
```

Pass the repository into your controller using dependancy injection and then call it using:

```
$candidate = $this->candidate->findBySlug($slug);
```

Here's some more reading: http://laravel.com/docs/ioc & http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/

Hope that helps.